# Prepending not working. My code works for normal print from double linked list. However, I want to prepend

Tags: c++

My code works for normal print from double linked list. However, I want to prepend( or print my data in reverse order then my input) my input. so i have comment the non working portion of the code. When I run the whole code, for some reason the loop doesn't closes for my reverse order print. it only keeps on printing the first number I input. Can you also suggest me how to delete all the memory i have allocated.

```
struct node{
    int data;
    node* next;
    node* prev;
};

struct node* head;

void printF(node* tail);
//void printR(node* head);

int main(){

    node* tail;
    node* n;
    int input;
    do {
        cout<<"Enter a positive number to add in the list or -1 to terminate the list: ";
        cin>>input;
        cout<<endl; 
        n= new node;
        if (input >=0){

            if(head == NULL){
                n->data=input;
                n->next=NULL;
                head=n; 
                tail = n;
            }
            n->data = input;
            n->prev =NULL;
            n->next=head;
            head->prev=n;
            head = n;
        }
        else if (input == -1)
        {
            head->prev=NULL;
            cout<<"Program terminated!!"<<endl;
        }
        else{
            cout<<"Your input is invalid!! Enter a positive number to add in the list or -1 to terminate the list"<<endl;
        }
    }while(input != -1);    
//  printR(head);
    printF(tail);

    //delete node;

}

/*
void printR(node* head){
    node* temp = head;
    while(temp!=NULL){
        cout<< temp->data<<", ";
        temp= temp->next;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
*/
///*
void printF(node* tail){
    node* temp = tail;
    while(temp!=NULL){
        cout<< temp->data<<", ";
        temp = temp->prev;
    }
    cout<<endl;
```

Comment: Take a close look at what your code does when adding the first data point.

Comment: Also, you should learn how to use a debugger. The bug in the shown code will be very obvious once you use your debugger to inspect all objects your program creates, and inspect all `next` and `prev` pointers, and see exactly what's broken with them.